# Virtualbox can ping but can't browse

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtualbox, bridge

I'm running **Virtualbox V 5.1.28**. I've VMS (Windows and Linux) with **bridged network adapter**. I can ping between all guests, also, I can successfully ping sites on the internet (ping google.com or www.google.com). My problem is that I can't browse the internet, my configurations for the guests:

- DHCP: Automatic
- DNS: Automatic

I checked my router and firewall, both work fine. I changed the setting to **NAT** and it worked fine. Also, I tried to Telnet, and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just install the **V 5.1.27**, and it WORKS somehow.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by running VirtualBox as admin